# Loop over big Lua table literal using ipairs doesn't do anything

Tags: lua

I come to Lua from Javascript, but there are some significant differences that cause me to do stupid things. I defined a table literal to hold some static data:

```
ObjectTypeDefs = {
  mailbox={
    time=40,
    yield={{name="Base.Plank"}, {name="Base.Newspaper"}, {name="Base.ScrapMetal"}},
    tools={{"Base.AxeStone", "Base.Axe"}},
    cheat=false,
    displayName="Mailbox"
  },
  laundry={
    time=300,
    yield={{name="Radio.ElectricWire"}, {name="Base.ScrapMetal"}},
    exp={electrical=3},
    tools={"Base.Screwdriver", "Base.KitchenKnife"},
    cheat=false,
    displayName="Laundry machine"
  },
  wood_chair={ ... and so on ...}

  ... more items here ...
}
```

Yo can see the `tools` sub-key in every entry. That defines some game tools required to perform some operation. I want to assign some validator function to all `tools` subkeys. I tried to do this:

```
  print("Initializing object definitions: ");
  -- Here, callbacks for definitions are assigned
  for i,v in ipairs(ObjectTypeDefs) do
    print("Defining checkItems callback for "..i..".");
    v.tools.checkItems = ... some closure here ...;
  end
```

But all output I get is:

```
Initializing object definitions:
```

The for loop doesn't even start. What's wrong with it? Here's runnable sample: http://ideone.com/QqYU04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`pairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs) to iterate over the hash part of a table. [`ipairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) are for iteration over a numeric part of a table (and is sometimes better replaced with numeric for).

This is not related to the question, but watch over your globals too. Are you sure that `ObjectTypeDefs` has to be a global variable?

Comment: At this moment, I don't know how to declare local variable. Lua doesn't seem to have self-calling closures like javascript does for that purpose. I'll read more on variable scopes, but `ObjectTypeDefs` probably has to remain global.

Comment: Use `local` just as you would use `var` in JS. Lua does have closures, but they are not needed in this case, since Lua has full lexical scoping. Get a recent edition of Programming in Lua, it is a worthy read for any programmer.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [`ipairs`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.2/index#pdf-ipairs) which iterates only over integer indices. You should instead use [`pairs`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.2/index#pdf-pairs).

Answer (score 3):

`ipairs` iterates over integer indices starting from `yourTable[1]` and ending at the first table element that is `nil`.

You have to use `pairs` or `next` (which is used by `pairs` internally). But keep in mind that output order is arbitrary.

```
for k,v in pairs(yourTable) do
  ...
end
```

or

```
for k,v in next, yourTable do
  ...
end
```

http://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html

Comment: Please note that you're linking to outdated version of PiL. Behaviour of `ipairs` is slightly different in modern Lua versions, AFAIR.

Comment: And what is the different behaviour? This is from the Lua 5.3 reference:
ipairs (t)

Returns three values (an iterator function, the table t, and 0) so that the construction

     for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end
will iterate over the key–value pairs (1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ..., up to the first nil value.

Comment: Indeed, I've got an impression that 5.3 stopped at random nil, but I was wrong. 5.3 `ipairs` has metamethods support, but it is not related to this question.